# Mysql SUM with case statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, case

```
SELECT 
    SUM(
        CASE 
           WHEN cumulative = 1 
           THEN percent 
           ELSE 0 
        END) 
FROM phppos_items_taxes;
```

Given the above statement does this do the following:

```
mysql> select * FROM phppos_items_taxes;
+---------+-----------+---------+------------+
| item_id | name      | percent | cumulative |
+---------+-----------+---------+------------+
|       1 | Tax 1     |    8.00 |          0 |
|       1 | Tax 2     |   10.00 |          1 |
|       3 | Sales Tax |    8.00 |          0 |
|       4 | Tax 1     |   20.00 |          0 |
|       4 | Tax 2     |   20.00 |          0 |
+---------+-----------+---------+------------+
```

Does this SUM up percent for each row that cumulative = 1. If cumulative != 1 then 0 is summed.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes it does!
A shorter and cleaner query (IMHO) would be to use `IF` statement:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(cumulative = 1, `percent`, 0)) FROM phppos_items_taxes;
```

Comment: Shorter, yes, but the IF() syntax is not ANSI SQL.  Using CASE increases the chance of being portable, for what that's worth.

Comment: @Bill: Yes, you are right. I totally agree with you. However, there are so many things in MySQL, which are not ANSI SQL, that will not make SQL code written for MySQL that portable by default. Chances are when portability comes to question all the queries will be inspected, but it's great that you brought it up, thanks. :)

Comment: Yes, I agree portability is elusive, and not always worth it.

Answer (score 7):

Why not just to filter out items?

```
SELECT 
    SUM(ISNULL(percent, 0)) 
FROM 
    phppos_items_taxes
WHERE 
    cumulative = 1
```

In your case each row will be selected and `CASE` statement has to be applied, I believe with `WHERE` filter it would be significantly faster because **WHERE clause executing before SELECT clause**

Comment: @Chris Muench: If the query does not involve other factors, use this solution, it is much faster indeed. :)